# What the name of this flower? They close at night n blooms in the morning

Tags: ornamental-plant

[image]

I have these plants at my home I Wana know the name the close at night n blooms in morning... Tnx

Answer (score 2):

That plant is [Oxalis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oxalis), also called wood sorrel or false shamrock. Oxalis is actually the genus; there are many species. Some of the larger species are sold as house plants, especially around St Patrick's Day (at least in the US, in areas where St Patrick's Day is a big deal). Some species are rather weedy; it was a problem in a greenhouse that I worked in. When ripe, the seed pods will burst open when disturbed. So we'd go to pull out one clump of oxalis, and seeds would shoot out and get into all the nearby planters.

As long as you haven't used any pesticides or fertilizers on that plant or the soil it's growing in, the leaves are quite good to eat. They have a pleasantly sour taste. The flavor is similar to the unrelated plant common sorrel (*Rumex acetosa*).